# Powershell: How to properly implement mode switch in parameters?

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have a code in my function that works well for me, was inspired by another SO answer, but is marked as improper in VSCode. I would like to improve on it, but currently I have no idea how.

```
Param(
    [Parameter( Mandatory = $True,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                Position = 0,
                ParameterSetName = "Info")]
    [switch] $Info = $false,

    [Parameter( Mandatory = $True,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                Position = 0,
                ParameterSetName = "Warn")]
    [switch] $Warn = $false,

    [Parameter( Mandatory = $True,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                Position = 0,
                ParameterSetName = "Error")]
    [switch] $Error = $false,

    [Parameter( Mandatory = $True,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                Position = 0,
                ParameterSetName = "Fatal")]
    [switch] $Fatal = $false,

    [Parameter( Mandatory = $True,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                Position = 0,
                ParameterSetName = "Debug")]
    [switch] $Debugging = $false,

)

switch ($PSBoundParameters.Keys) {
    'Info' { $level = "INFO"
             $color = "Green" }
    'Warn' { $level = "WARNING"
             $color = "Yellow" }
    'Error' { $level = "ERROR"
              $color = "Red" }
    'Fatal' { $level = "FATAL"
              $color = "DarkRed" }
    'Debugging' { $level = "DEBUG"
                  $color = "Magenta" }
}
```

The error is https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/master/RuleDocumentation/AvoidDefaultValueForMandatoryParameter.md - I get that, but how to transform this code so that it is kosher and still performs the same function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSSA complains because the `Mandatory` flag applies to the *user* - the user *must* specify arguments for all parameters marked `Mandatory` in a parameter set - and since the user is already *required* to supply arguments, it makes no sense to default values, PowerShell will never use them.

The local variables corresponding to the switch parameters in the parameter sets NOT chosen will default to a `$null`-like value, equivalent to `$false` anyway:

```bsh
Param(
    [Parameter( Mandatory = $True,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                Position = 0,
                ParameterSetName = "Info")]
    [switch] $Info,

    [Parameter( Mandatory = $True,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                Position = 0,
                ParameterSetName = "Warn")]
    [switch] $Warn,

    [Parameter( Mandatory = $True,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                Position = 0,
                ParameterSetName = "Error")]
    [switch] $Error,

    [Parameter( Mandatory = $True,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                Position = 0,
                ParameterSetName = "Fatal")]
    [switch] $Fatal,

    [Parameter( Mandatory = $True,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
                Position = 0,
                ParameterSetName = "Debug")]
    [switch] $Debugging,

)
```

Comment: Also switches are default $false so those assignments should be removed

Comment: @DougMaurer as mentioned the "local variables corresponding to the switch parameters in the parameter sets NOT chosen will default to a `$null`-like value, equivalent to `$false` anyway"

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks!